# Elasticsearch “data”: { “type”: “float” } query returns incorrect results

Tags: elasticsearch, types, field

I have a query like below and when date_partition field is "type" => "float" it returns queries like 20220109, 20220108, 20220107.
When field "type" => "long", it only returns 20220109 query. Which is what I want.

Each queries below, the result is returned as if the query 20220119 was sent.
--> 20220109, 20220108, 20220107

```
PUT date
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "date_partition_float": {
        "type": "float"
      },
      "date_partition_long": {
        "type": "long"
      }
    }
  }
}
POST date/_doc
{
  "date_partition_float": "20220109",
  "date_partition_long": "20220109"
}
#its return the query
GET date/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "date_partition_float": "20220108"
    }
  }
}
#nothing return
GET date/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "date_partition_long": "20220108"
    }
  }
}
```

Is this a bug or is this how float type works ?
2 years of data loaded to Elasticsearch (like day-1, day-2) (20 gb pri shard size per day)(total 15 TB) what is the best way to change the type of just this field ?
I have 5 float type in my mapping, what is the fastest way to change all of them.
Note: In my mind I have below solutions but I'm afraid it's slow

- update by query API
- reindex API
- run time search request (especially this one)
  Thank you!
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

That `date_partition` field should have the `date` type with `format=yyyyMMdd`, that's the only sensible type to use, not `long` and even worse `float`.

```
PUT date
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "date_partition": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyyMMdd"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's not logical to query for `20220108` and have the `20220109` document returned in the results.

Using the `date` type would also allow you to use proper time-based `range` queries and create `date_histogram` aggregations on your data.

You can either recreate the index with the adequate type and reindex your data, or add a new field to your existing index and update it by query. Both options are valid.

Comment: Hi Val, Thank you for respond. I know it's not make sense but its happen.
I'm trying to figure what why

Comment: Use the right type for the data, i.e. a `date` field and you'll be fine

Answer (score 1):

It can be answer of my question => https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-data-type-float-returns-incorrect-results/300335

> You're running into some java quirks (built as intended however) here.
> If you want to reproduce, run jshell locally and type in this
>
> Float.valueOf(20220109.0f); the result will return 2.0220108E7 due to
> rounding issues with floating point values, as they are not stored
> exactly.
>
> You can use the reindex functionality to reindex your data into an
> index with the mapping fixed (you could also add new fields to the
> existing index and use update-by-query, but I am not sure that is
> clean).