Elasticsearch rounds long number
I have an index in opensearch (elasticsearch) with a number field defined as long. Java LONG type has max value = 2^63, but when I try to write a number 2^53 + 1 to the index, it will write the rounded number, not equal to 2^53 + 1. Please explain what is the matter. The maximum number that is not rounded when writing is 2^53 = 9007199254740992.
I write 9007199254740992, in elastic 9007199254740992
I write 9007199254740993, but in elastic again 9007199254740992

You're running into some java quirks (built as intended however) here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71572203/elasticsearch-data-type-float-query-returns-incorrect-results

I'm not using floating point values

I don't know anything about elasticsearch, but it seems to use Java, so maybe long literals need to be suffixed with l or L? Try 9007199254740993L and see if it works.

This one might help too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38952262/elasticsearch-max-length-of-mapping-type-long

Thank you! You're right, elastic works correctly, but the browser (JS) rounds long values.
